# iCloud says "Encountered an error while trying to respond to the roll of the baseline" using Magical Record

Tags: ios5, icloud, magicalrecord

I am setting up my iOS app to use Magical Record and iCloud. Magical Record appears to be starting up and initialising the iCloud container successively. It then reports an error when trying to save "baseline.zip" Any suggestion as to what is going wrong would be very appreciated. Below is the stacktrace.

Many thanks,
Joel

```
2012-11-22 16:51:07:918 ThatsIt[1803:907] -> Created <NSManagedObjectContext (0x21055f20): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2012-11-22 16:51:07:919 ThatsIt[1803:907] Set Root Saving Context:    <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x21055f20>
2012-11-22 16:51:07:919 ThatsIt[1803:907] Created Main Queue Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x21056a30>
2012-11-22 16:51:07:920 ThatsIt[1803:907] Set Default Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x21056a30>
2012-11-22 16:51:07:943 ThatsIt[1803:907] DDlog is running okay
2012-11-22 16:51:09.764 ThatsIt[1803:3a0b] -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter rollResponseOperation:encounteredAnError:whileTryingToAdoptBaseline:](1509): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityBaselineRollResponseOperation: 0x2105eb20> localPeerID:  mobile.EF865F29-F719-5648-8C0F-0F9CE63C520F, storeName: com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt,  modelVersionHash: 47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x21063cc0>:   /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt

Encountered an error while trying to respond to the roll of baseline: <PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x1fd956a0>(0)
permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile  Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip
safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd94110>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile  Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj 8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/mobile.EF865F29-F719-5648-8C0F-0F9CE63C520F
currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip

storeName: com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt
modelVersionHash: 47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile  Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip

Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134310 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134310.)" UserInfo=0x1fd8bbe0 {baseline=<PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x1fd956a0>(0)
permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip
safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd94110>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/mobile.EF865F29-F719-5648-8C0F-0F9CE63C520F
currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip

storeName: com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt
modelVersionHash: 47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
baselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile  Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj 8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip, localStoreKV=<PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x1fd7d070> ()}
userInfo: {
baseline = "<PFUbiquityBaseline: 0x1fd956a0>(0)\n\tpermanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip\n\tsafeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd94110>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/mobile.EF865F29-F719-5648-8C0F-0F9CE63C520F\n\tcurrentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip\n\n\tstoreName: com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt\n\tmodelVersionHash: 47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=\n\tbaselineArchiveLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1fd91ab0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/F8MBU8E2WX~com~mirthfullife~ThatsIt/.baseline/com.mirthfullife.ThatsIt/47DEQpj8HBSa~_TImW~5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=/baseline.zip\n";
localStoreKV = "<PFUbiquityKnowledgeVector: 0x1fd7d070> ()";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have the same here. After searching the web I only found the hint to [clean the build, delete the application from the device and rebuild it again](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=242&t=5411). This however didn't solve my problem, but the app worked as intended.

As soon as I created some data for the first time, the error disappeared so it might "only" be an initial error, although it feels quite frustrating..

Comment: thanks Thomas, I'll give that a try, it appears promising as having no data is also my case.

Answer (score 1):

This basically means that iCloud was expecting to see some data in your iCloud folder,   you have an iCloud folder (that you just created),  but nothing (data) was in it...

it appears that Apple is expecting you to seed the store right away before using it.

to fix temporarily,  put some data in it that iCloud would expect from your app.  (in otherwords use your app)

it looks like to fix it permanently,  (for your users upon start up)  seed the store with some throw away variable before it tries to read.

(in otherwords if you get rid of all the files (including the actual folders) in your iCloud store/ temp store/ fall back store,  this error should come back when you first run the app and don't seed the store)

anyway that should provide someone with some experimenting to do :o)

atleast this is what i believe is happening.   If I discover something different,  i'll add to the answer.